# Azure: Australia East vs Australia Southeast

Tags: azure

I'm in the process of configuring a VM in Azure, and when I got to the region selection, I noticed that "Australia East" is in the "recommended" sub-section, but "Australia Southeast" is in the "other" section.

I can't find any additional information about why one of these regions is apparently prefered over the other.

Can anyone shed any light on this? Is there some actual technical reason why the "Australia East" region would be recommended over Melbourne?

From a geographic point of view "Southeast" is better for me, but if the servers are newer, or networks faster in "East" then obviously I'll use that instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the recommended regions are either going to have more capacity currently, or be a larger region.

Answer (score 1):

If Southeast is close to you, Australia Central 2 might be close as well.

Spin up tests in the candidate regions. See what latency and feature availability is like.

The second best in your selection could remain as an alternate region, if your business continuity plans span multiple regions.

Answer (score 1):

As of July 2020 (after you asked the question) Australia East is the only Australian region with Azure Availability Zones, which can offer increased single-region resilience (if it's important for your use case).